# Java jax-ws : force xjc (and wsimport etc.) to ONLY use catalog entries for imported schemas

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, xjc, wsimport

I have an issue with how some tools in the jax-ws toolchain (`xjc` and possibly `wsimport` as well) behave when trying to import XSD files in conjunction with a provided catalog.

For instance, I understand that `xjc` when provided with a catalog file (see [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html) for an example), will pick-up the imported schema from the location indicated in the catalog, even if the `<xs:import>` element has a valid, `xs:schemaLocation` that's properly hosted and from which the schema can be fetched over the network.

So far so good as it makes sense for the catalog entries to override `schemaLocation` attributes.

However, if the catalog file indicates a local filesystem location and for some reason, e.g. a mistyping in the directory path, the catalog-provided location is not accessible, the `xjc` tool will silently revert back to the `xs:schemaLocation` value and retrieve the file from there. To make matters worse this behavior only occurs (as far as I can tell from some tests I did) if the entry is marked "PUBLIC" in the catalog - if it is is marked "SYSTEM" the `xjc` tool will indeed complain.

**So, my question is:**

To always have a consistent behavior, is there a way to **disable** `xjc`'s fetching from `schemaLocation` attributes and force it to always lookup imported schemas on the catalog and fail spectacularly if they are not found? Note that this is not the same as asking how to disable `xjc`'s network fetching functionality as I suppose it may still be useful in some cases to indicate an intranet location on the catalog file.

Failing the above, some way to disable all network accesses during an `xjc` or `wsimport` run?